# Outlook 2010 Add-in 

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, outlook-2010

I am writing custom code in Outlook Add-in using SharePoint Web Services to create a meeting workspace in SharePoint. Then I add a meeting to the workspace created.
Basically I want to mimic the functionality provided by Outlook itself.

The problem is after a meeting is created, I can not set the `MeetingWorkspaceUrl` property in `AppointmentItem` using my custom code. It says the property is read only. 
But when I create a workspace using default Outlook functionality, I can see that `MeetingWorkspaceUrl` is set to a valid URL.

Can I do the same thing through custom code?

Answer (score 1):

[`MeetingWorkspaceUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librAry/ff869948) [is readonly in the **Outlook API**](http://help.wugnet.com/office/Settings-MeetingWorkspaceURL-property-ftopict946960.html), you need to use **EWS** (*[`AppointmentItem.MeetingWorkspaceUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.meetingworkspaceurl%28v=exchg.80%29)*) to assign its value.

Comment: Hi SilverNinja, I don't want to create an appointment using EWS. I am opening a new appointment in outlook and then using sharepoint Meetings web service to create a meeting.Is there a way I can set this property using sharepoint? please help.

Comment: You don't have to create the appointment using EWS - you could just modify the URL property using the create `Meeting` ID. What sharepoint web service method are you using from [meetings.asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772617%28v=office.12%29)? Are you using [`AddMeeting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/meetings.meetings.addmeeting%28v=office.12%29)?

Comment: If you are using `AddMeeting`, the location of [**MWSURL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee218542%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) is inferred by which web service address you used to add the meeting (*/sites/workspaceArea/_vti_bin/meetings.asmx*). See [MSDN on creating a new workspace site and adding a meeting to the new site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477384%28v=office.12%29.aspx).